# Deleting an item from an array after randomization

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So there is an array of two different urls for images. My code calls for the array to be randomized and to put the randomized src in one of the img tags. Here is what it looks like:

```
var movieArray = ['http://gdj.gdj.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/grey-movie-poster.jpg', 'http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/sites/default/files/custom/Blog_Images/avengers-movie-poster-1.jpg'];
    var randomSrc1 = movieArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * movieArray.length)];
    var randomSrc2 = movieArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * movieArray.length)];
        $('#movie1_img').attr('src', '' + randomSrc1 + '');
        $('#movie2_img').attr('src', '' + randomSrc2 + '');
```

This works fine, but now there is the problem of having the two images being the same. I don't know how to prevent this. After the first src is given to the movie1_img tag do i need to delete that src from the array using .grep or something else?

Comment: Shuffle the array instead  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6274381/1414562

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/245069/1393766)

Comment: To avoid the prob of having the same img get rid of it once chosen.  You can shuffle and then remove by shift() or splice() at the given index

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Array.prototype.slice()` , `Array.prototype.splice()`

```
var movieArray = ['http://gdj.gdj.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/grey-movie-poster.jpg', 'http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/sites/default/files/custom/Blog_Images/avengers-movie-poster-1.jpg'];
// create copy of `movieArray`
var movies = movieArray.slice();
// get random item from within `movies`
var randomSrc1 = movies.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length), 1);
// get remainding item from within `movies`
var randomSrc2 = movies.splice(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Shuffle the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6274381/1414562) instead:

```
function shuffle(o){
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
}

var movieArray = shuffle(['http://gdj.gdj.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/grey-movie-poster.jpg', 'http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/sites/default/files/custom/Blog_Images/avengers-movie-poster-1.jpg']);
$('img[id^=movie][id$=_img]').attr('src', function(i){
    return movieArray[i];
});
```

### -jsFiddle-